# Access form controls values in AngularJS without data binding

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have a form which is generated by rails scaffolding and which works correctly. I want to add a new Angular controller in this form to compute a kind of score / progress bar to show to the user the percentage completion of his application.

I am facing a problem within update. Actually,

- Rails is assigning a value to the form control
- ngModel is resetting that controller since I didn't initialize the values in the javascript part.

In the code below, during edit, the side_id control become empty.

Is there a clean way to read the form different controls without doing any data binding?

```
  <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#general" data-toggle="tab">Données générales</a></li>
    <li><a href="#location" data-toggle="tab">Location</a></li>
    <li><a href="#suppl" data-toggle="tab">Données supplémentaires</a></li>
    <li><a href="#photos" data-toggle="tab">Photos</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane mypanel active" id="general">
      <br/>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :side_id %><br>
            <%= f.collection_select(:side_id, Side.all,:id,:label,{}, {:class => "form-control", "ng-model" => "side_id"}) %>
            {{side_id}}
          </div>          
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="field">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
side_id = angular.element('#classified_side_id').val();
```

In addition I am listenting for the element value change using events.

Answer (score 0):

You can create directive to init value in `ngModel` by default value from `html`.

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/c5eq4869/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {
    $scope.options = [{
      id: 0,
      name: "No"
    }, {
      id: 1,
      name: "Yes"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: "Unknow"
    }];
  })
  .directive('initValue', function() {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      require: "ngModel",
      scope: {
        initValue: "=",
        ngModel: "="
      },
      link: function(scope) {
        scope.ngModel = scope.initValue;
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <input ng-model="id" init-value="'dfdffd'">
    <pre>id={{id}}</pre>
    <select ng-model="idSelect" init-value="'2'">
      <option value="0">No</option>
      <option value="1">Yes</option>
      <option value="2">Unknow</option>
    </select>
    <pre>idSelect={{idSelect}}</pre>
    <select ng-model="idSelect2" init-value="1" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in options">
    </select>
    <pre>idSelect2={{idSelect2}}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```